# Can subdomains be hosted on a separate server?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain

Say there is a website, `www.website1.example`, that is hosted on a web server, web server A. Is it possible to have another website, `www.something.website1.example` on a different web server, web server B?
Or is the `www.something.website1.example` still considered a sub domain of `www.website1.example`, and must be hosted on the same web server, A?

For clarification: `www.website1.example` is hosted on a third party web server, but a client wants us to host `www.something.website1.example` on one of our own web servers, NOT the third party. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS change; where ever the DNS for `website1.example` is handled you want to add an **A record** for `www.something.website1.example` to point to the new IP address.

Then on the Server B, of course, you need to let the HTTP server (Apache, lighttpd, etc) know that it is serving for that name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible. You just need to ask your provider to have the URL `www.something.website1.example` point to your second website on the server B.

It's like having a website and a webmail with  different providers.

Comment: Technically, `www.something.website1.example` is an hostname, not an URL. And indeed the DNS deals with names and not URLs, and the DNS is used to map names to addresses with `A` records for IPv4 addresses, and `AAAA` records for IPv6 addresses.